# Is there any way to import cookies in Netscape format into Google Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

There is a lot of add-ons, which provides possibility to import cookie in JSON format into Chrome Browser. But I cannot find any, which provides possibility to import cookie in Netscape format into Chrome.

Do you know some plugins, which provide such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Get cookies.txt

Exports your cookies to the Netscape cookie file format a.k.a. cookies.txt which is compatible with wget, curl, youtube-dl and more.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-cookiestxt/bgaddhkoddajcdgocldbbfleckgcbcid